# Не получается подключится к БД firebird через библиотеку fdb

Tags: python, база-данных, firebird

не получается подключится в db firebird на python с помощью библиотеки fdb, при выполнении кода получаю вывод ошибки `raise Exception("The location of Firebird Client Library could not be determined.") Exception: The location of Firebird Client Library could not be determined.`
Пробовал добавлять в path папку с исполняемым скриптом а также добавлял dll-ку GDS32.DLL в \Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\fdb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась установкой клиентского компонента Firebird